# I want to notify users about recent updates for my android application

Tags: android, http, notifications

I want to notify my app users about recent updates through weekly notifications and I'll put in the content. How to do it?

Comment: Use push notification.

Comment: Take a look  at [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). This gives you the possibility, to send notifications from a server to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Playstore send default update notification for your app, if you notify users apart from that,

1. When app launches you can make a API request to check new version availability and prompt users about update available.
2. Implement Broadcast receiver to your app and send push notification to mobile.
3. If you have stored your users Email id or Mobile number ,you can notify them by this way.